# how to set up sequelize for existing sails project

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

```js
    // finding users
    find:  function (req, res, next) {
      var userId = req.body.userId;
      var userSchema = db.UserModel;
      try {

        db.sequelize.sync().then(function (params) {
          userSchema.findAll({where:{userId:userId}}).then(function (user) {

            return res.json({
              success:true,
              userData:user.get({
                plain:true
              })
            });

          });

        });

      } catch (ex) {
        res.json({
          success: false,
          exception: ex
        });
        return;
      }
    }
```

I was writting simple crud api for my project.
while executing above mentioned code I am getting error on my console as:

> Executing (default): SELECT `userId`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`userId` = '1';
>   Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at D:\tecsol\mtv\api\controllers\UserController.js:52:27
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is an array - use [`findOne`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findoneoptions-promiseinstance) or `user[0]`